# What are the .lyx~ files for?

Tags: lyx

What are the .Lyx~ files that Lyx is saving near my normal files for?
They don't seem to be temp files as these are marked #*.lyx#, and they don't go away.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are files created by your editor. Traditionally files that end with a tilde are to be seen as backups of files with the same name but without the tilde. See the [wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tilde#Backup_filenames) for an explanation.

Comment: Ohh I see.. thank you. Does this mean it's safe to just delete them?

Comment: Yes. There should also be a setting that lets you put them in other directories.

Answer (score 3):

For the reference of those who stumble across this page in future, like me, [here's](https://www.mail-archive.com/lyx-users@lists.lyx.org/msg78488.html) a more detailed answer from the lyx users' mailing archive.

Apparently, the `*.lyx~` files are used to recover the file when a *save* fails. The `#*.lyx#` files are used to automatically backup the file every so many minutes. The latter are automatically deleted when the file is saved. The former are not.